# Rails: accessing the values of columns selected with column_names

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, hash

Any ideas what it takes to get this to work? I can't for the life of me figure it out.

```
def get_prices(c)
  @print_prices = {}
  Billing.where(:name => c).column_names.each do |d|
    if d.match(/^print_/)
      @print_prices[d] = d.value
    end
  end
  return @print_prices
end
```

I've got no idea what to substitute `d.value` for.

Cheers for any help.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: I'm trying to build a hash of values, i.e., `{"print_100"=>"30", "print_200"=>"60", "print_500"=>"90"}`. The key is the column name, the value is the column's value.

Comment: And you expect `Billing.where(:name => c)` to return just one record in the relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will perform the query, returned in the form of a relation, and reject all items in the attribute key-value hash which do not match the given regex, which, in this case, is `/^print_/`.

```
def get_prices(c)
  Billing.where(:name => c).first.attributes.reject{ |i| !i.match(/^print_/) }
end
```

Alternatively, it can also be written as:

```
def get_prices(c)
  Billing.where(:name => c).first.attributes.select{ |i| i.match(/^print_/) }
end
```

Comment: Cheers! Works great. And yeah, double negatives are always confusing. Ha.